# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:8080, http://localhost:8080, http://localhost:8080'

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:8080, http://localhost:8080, http://localhost:8080', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

My code is:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "http://tilesdev1.intra.schneider.com/api/fa-snihelp-service/entserv",
     type: "GET",
     dataType: 'json',
     headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
     },
     xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: true
     },
     crossDomain: true,
     success: function (result) {
                debugger;
     },
     error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                console.error(error);
     },
});
```

Comment: What is your question? Is the error message not clear?

Comment: what is programming language you are using in server side?

Comment: check the headers of the response from your server side - the problem is most likely there

Comment: install CORS extension to chrome and then try

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.